# How to finish specific tab activity in tab activity android

Tags: android, tabs, out-of-memory

I have problems with many tab of activities while using tab activity in android. I have 12 tabs with viewpager inside of each activity. The problems I got was the memory always run out of memory with this error message

**out of memory on a 296 byte allocation**

I don't know how to make efficient of using memory allocation while I use tab activity. The plan that I consider is just to dispose another tab activity. But how can I do that?

Comment: Use viewpager with fragments.

Comment: What do you mean using fragments?

Comment: I think you need this :-http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html

Comment: is there any difference in using viewpager using fragments comparing to tab activity?

Comment: Huge difference as fragments are loaded and unloaded by view pager automatically while swiping the view. and you can set the off screen page limit for this.